# what IP should be used in hosts when setting up the mail server?

Tags: debian, email-server, ip, hosts

I'm setting up a mail server on my debian by following the [tecmint](https://www.tecmint.com/install-postfix-mail-server-with-webmail-in-debian/) tutorial.

In step 4  the ip should be added in the hosts file.

```
# hostnamectl set-hostname mail.mydomain.com
# echo "192.168.0.102 mydomain.com mail.mydomain.com" >> /etc/hosts
```

what kind of IP i have to use here? is that the locale ip of the machine or the IP of the server(Internet ip)?

if it is the local IP, can I also use `localhost` here?

Comment: Shouldn't it be # echo "192.168.0.102 mail mail.mydomain.com" >> /etc/hosts ?

Answer (score 1):

You must put IP address there, `localhost` or any other name is not allowed. It must be IP address available locally on your server. If your server has internet IP assigned to one of its interfaces, use it here, otherwise you may use local IP. There is no much difference as long as this IP is assigned to your server - use `ip addr show` to check if unsure.

Answer (score 1):

In `/etc/hosts`, you can define the (local) mapping of hostnames to IPs. Thus, you cannot put `localhost` here, because you want to map the IP of your server to the hostname `mail.mydomain.com`. You cannot map hostnames to hostnames this way.

Normally, you should map the Internet accessible IP to the Internet accessible (FQN) hostname (like `mail.mydomain.com`).
In any case, it must be an IP that your server can access itself through. Sometimes, e.g, behind a NAT (like a home router connecting multiple devices to the Internet), it can make sense to use a local IP like `192.168.0.102` or even `127.0.0.1` here. This way, you do not necessarily need the NAT reflection of your router to work correctly.

In any case, the local IP can (additionally) be mapped to a local hostname. The loopback IP `127.0.0.1` usually is mapped to `localhost` by default. You can additionally map local hostnames like `mailserver1` to local IPs like `192.168.0.102`.